# Github desktop revert commit results in >>> HEAD even in a new cloned repository

Tags: git, github, commit, git-revert, github-desktop

I try to revert a commit on Github Desktop. There was conflicts so I deleted the whole project and cloned it again to have a completely fresh clone.

Still after I reverted the commit I get things like ">>> HEAD". Why can't it just go back to previous commit?

I've made an animated gif of what I do:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reverting—i.e., asking Git to *undo*—the changes from a commit that is not the most recent commit.

If you intend to *revert to* that commit, i.e., to undo the changes that came *after* that commit, you should revert the subsequent commit.

See also [How to revert Git repository to a previous commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4114095/1256452)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be misunderstanding GIT,

> Still after I reverted the commit I get things like ">>> HEAD". Why can't it just go back to previous commit?

What you mean: Lets go back 1 entry in the revision history

What you try to do: Revert changes from the 2th revision change

You should revert the top commit, that way you go back 1 version in time.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, if I need to back 10 commits, I should back 10 times with the most recent first?